# How to check which titles/files are missing and why?

Tags: php, mysql

```
select count(*) id from arts where what = 'file';
```

result - `1713`

```
select title, count(*) c from arts group by title having c > 1;
```

result - `zero` - so there is no duplicates

```
$st = $db->query("select id, title, content from arts where what = 'file' order by title asc");
$st->execute();
$err = '';
while($row = $st->fetch()){
    $path = '../temp/' . $row['title'];
    $file = fopen($path . '.html', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    if(!$file){
        $err .= $row['title'] . ', ';
    } 
    fwrite($file, $row['content']);
    fclose($file);
}

echo $err;
```

nothing is echoed, there is no any error or warning and `1711` files are created.

So two files are missing.

I checked titles - there is no double spaces, leading and trailing spaces, titles are alphanumeric only...

How to check which titles/files are missing and why?

Comment: I presume you use `mysqli`? Then you can use `$st->num_rows` to get number of rows returned.

Comment: Perhaps you are running into a maximum file name length issue, and you have 2 titles which in that length are the same?

Comment: in Linux file names are case sensitive, but in Windows they are not. Are you using Windows?

Comment: if you use "x" instead of "w" as argument to fopen it will fail if file already exists